# How to restore a previous version of file in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, restore, file-recovery

I would like to restore a previous version of file that has been saved. My computer has crashed during work on one of the Files in Notepad++. When I started it again it went blank and a few days of my work are basically gone.

Is there any way to restore it?

Answer (score 19):

I know this question is ancient, but I thought someone would benefit from my solution. I had NP++ crash while trying to save my file and the result was losing not only the changes but the original file as well. I did some digging around in the directory structure of my user account (`C:\users\<user>\`) and found that there is a handy temporary folder for NP++. It had the copy of my file which was to be written to the disk.

Check this location if you have the same problem and are using Windows 7: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup`

Comment: This saved me from hours or rebuilding a page that I thought was gone for good!  thanks!!

Comment: no backup folder at said path :(

Comment: In Windows 7, the quickest way to get to the backup folder is by entering "%AppData%\Notepad++\backup" in an Explorer window address bar.

Answer (score 12):

Notepad++ does have file versioning.

In **Settings > Preferences > Backup** there is an option "Verbose backup".

[image]

This saves a new copy of the file into the "Custom Backup Directory". The current date/time is appended to the filename.

With "Simple backup" just the previous version of the file is saved.

Comment: Settings > Preferences > Backup tab > Click Verbose Backup This will time stamp a copy of your file every time you save.

Comment: The saved file has a .bak extension which can be opened by any text editor.

Answer (score 6):

Check Windows previous versions, right click, Properties, Previous Versions

[image: Previous Versions]

Answer (score 2):

I encounter a similar problem, where I overwrote an important file in Notepad++ and thankfully I was able to go to the file location, I right-clicked on the file, and selected "restore previous versions". From there I chose the latest version prior to the override and everything looks good for me.