# Recovering data corrupted by an AutoHotkey script?

Tags: notepad++, data-recovery, autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotkey scripts for automating note taking stuff. Today, some problem occurred and Notepad++ did not respond. I closed the window, and after opening the file, I saw that all my data had become corrupted.

I now have the following:

[image: Screenshot of data]

I've looked in `C:\Users\q\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup` and I cannot find the file there. The file extension is `.adoc`.

How can I recover the data?

Comment: Search your file in the Recycle Bin - it might contain some version of your file. Try also [previous versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17119/windows-7-recover-lost-deleted-files) although the chances are slim.

Comment: If your life depends on it, then of course you have it backed up in multiple on & off-site locations. Just get the most recent of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to recover unsaved notepad++ docs?](https://superuser.com/questions/975594/is-there-any-way-to-recover-unsaved-notepad-docs)

Answer (score 1):

Check Windows previous versions, right click, Properties, Previous Version https://superuser.com/a/390269/902014.

Lessons Learned 
* Back up Data Frequently do not trust any software that seems backup for you
(Notepad++ do not Backup files like office programs )
By by Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

Most (though not all) unattended program and scripts simply delete files and bypass the Recycle Bin.

You should immediately stop writing to the drive to avoid overwriting any data that is still on the disk.

There are numerous programs that can scan your disk for "deleted" files (files or fragments that have been marked as deleted, but the actual disk cluster hasn't been overwritten by other data yet). Some examples are "Directory Snoop 5.11" and "Restoration v2.5.14". These are both rather old, even at the time of this writing, but they still work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, Directory Snoop 5.11 have found my file(e.adoc) in LiveKernelRepots (in win32k.sys-20180816-2304 crash dump file) How can I retrieve via this crash dump file?

Comment: @my-lord Not sure. That would be a good topic for another question. Just make sure to be detailed and specific, and stick to one topic.